# Meteor - keybindings and value of a range element produce unbelieveable results

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using [meteor-keybindings](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-keybindings) and the following code:

```
Meteor.Keybindings.add({
  'plus' : function () { zoome.value -= -(zoome.value-90); },
  '-' : function () { zoome.value -= 10; },
  '*' : function () { zoome.value = 100; }
});
```

- I had to write the above code for a solid solution around this misty bug...

Scenario:

I have a range element with min value of 100 and max value of 500 to zoom a page.
the zoome.value += 10 jumps right up to 500, what's behind the scene?
The minus and reset functions work well...

Comment: repro?                     (padding)

Comment: I've improved your question and voted to keep it open, but you might want to clarify what you're asking.